# What does model.create! mean when used in a Rails controller concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mixins, activesupport, activesupport-concern

What does the `model.create!` expression mean:

```
module StandardCreateAction
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def create
   model.create!(attributes)
   render text: 'SUCCESS', status: self.class::SUCCESS_STATUS
  end
end
```

I'm guessing it calls a same name model in the controller that uses this mixin?

Comment: It calls 'create' on whatever is returned by 'model'. You need to figure out where the 'model' method is defined, and see what it returns.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that the model variable can't be defined anywhere else that I know if.  Because the class extends active concern and has no mixins.  So I was thinking it was either rails magic or something Im not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `model` has nothing to do with `ActiveSupport::Concern` which is just syntactic sugar around common ruby idioms such as:

```
module SomeMixin
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.class_eval do
      def foo
      end
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def bar
    end
  end
end
```

In this specific case`model` would be resolved to `self.model` in the class which includes or is extended by the module. If `self.model` cannot be resolved there it goes up the class tree.

I'm guessing its something along these lines:

```
def model
  self.class_name.chomp("Controller").singularize.constantize
end
```

However, you might want to to a look at [ActionController::Responder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html) and the [responders gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) before you go reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You sir were amazingly correct.   I didn't think to look in the calling class.   You were even right about the model method chomping the controller off the end.